# Issue with UITabBar, multiple UINavigationController and device orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I have a UITabBar with 2 UINavigationController created in my AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...

    UINavigationController *navController1, *navController2;
    PolyPage *viewController1 = [[PolyPage alloc] init];
    PolyPage *viewController2 = [[PolyPage alloc] init];

    navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController1, navController2, nil];

    ...
    return YES
}
```

My view controllers are the same. In PolyPage.m I have the method :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{    
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:CGPointMake(150, self.tableView.contentOffset.y + 240)];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        imageViewer = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithDataSource:[NSArray arrayWithObject:cell.imageView.image]];
        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:imageViewer animated:YES];
    }
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

This method shows my modal view controller only with the first navigation controller in the UITabBar.
I would like to make it work with both navigation controllers.